# a problem in linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The problem says to show that the mapping $T:P(R)->P(R)$ defined by

$$T(f(x))=\int_0^x f(t) \ dt$$

is a linear transformation which is injective  but not surjective(Friedberg BOOK,PAGE-75,problem no -15)

Now my question is that why $T$ is acting on $f(x)$(i.e the image) instead of acting on the member of $P(R)$ i.e on the function $f$ and what is the role of $x$ in the definition of $T$(i.e,my point is to understand the definition of $T$ explicitly).

secondly,assuming the definition(without understanding it properly) i have shown that $T$ is linear but i got stuck in showing that $T$ is injective(tried to show that $Ker\ T=\{0\}$ but failed) and most importantly not surjective(in proving not surjective i am not seeing any clue)

any kind of help to this problem is welcome.

Comment: What exactly is meant by $P(R)$?

Comment: P(R) is the vector space of all polynomial functions with real coefficients from R to R over the field R(R stands for field of all real numbers),and can also be viewed as a subspace of C(R)[the infinite dimensional vector space of all continuous functions from R to R over the field R].

Answer (score 1):

While $P(\mathbb{R})$ is a codomain, it is also a domain of $T$, so maybe you are confusing yourself a bit. $f(x)$ may be an image, and but it is also a member of $P(R)$.

The transformation $T$ is mapping a polynomial function $P(\mathbb{R})$ to another polynomial function in $P(\mathbb{R})$. For instance:

$x+1 \in P(\mathbb{R})$ and $\displaystyle T(x+1)=\int_{0}^{x} t+1 \, dt = \frac{x^2}{2} +x \in P(\mathbb{R}) $

This is linear since integration is clearly a linear mapping.

For injectivity, suppose that $T(f)=0$. Since $f$ is a polynomial with real coefficients, you can definitely express it in explicit form

$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x^k
$$

Then what is $T(f)$? What does the condition $T(f)=0$ tell you about coefficients of $f$?

Answer (score 0):

$P(\mathbb R)$ denotes the set of all polynomial with real coefficients.

i.e., $P(\mathbb R)=\{f(x)\  |\ f(x)= a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +\dots +a_1x^1+a_o, a_i \in \mathbb R\}.$

Here,  $T(f(x))=\int_0^x \ f(t) \ dt = \int_0^x \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i= \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{a_i}{i+1}x^{i+1}$

$ \because T(f(x)+g(x))= \int_0^x(f(t)+g(t))\ dt=\int_0^x f(t)\ dt + \int_0^x g(t)\ dt =T(f(x))+T(g(x))$,  we have $T$ is *linear*.

Suppose $Ker\ T \neq \{0\}.$ Then there is a non zero polynomial $f(x)$ in $P(\mathbb R)$ such that $T(f(x)) = 0.$ 
$\implies \int_0^xf(x)=0 \implies f(x)=0,$ a contradiction. Hence $Ker\ T =\{0\}.$

Consider a constant polynomial $f(x) = k $ for some $k \in \mathbb R.$ There is no $f(x)\in P(\mathbb R)$ such that  $\int_0^x f(x) =k.$ Therefore constant polynomials does not have pre images, hence $T$ is *not onto*.

Comment: Thank you Uma Maheswari N.lenin.But my view is that a constant polynomial other than zero polynomial has no premiage(as zero polynomial is its own preimage).And secondly i suppose that you wanted to write P(R) is the set of all polynomial functions with real coefficients but  missed the word function.I am saying this because how can one integrate  or differentiate a polynomial as in polynomial x is an indeterminate and not a variable whereas  it is a variable in case of a polynomial function with respect to which one can integrate or differentiate it.